# Superfish plugin: $.fn.extend({...}) -- How does this code work?

Tags: jquery, plugins, overriding

Superfish JS is [here](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/js/superfish.js).

Here's the relevant code:

```
$.fn.extend({
    hideSuperfishUl : function() {
        // ...code here...
        return this;
    },
    showSuperfishUl : function(){
        // ...code here...
        return this;
    }
});
```

Questions:

Does `$.fn.extend({...});` allow users to override `hideSuperfishUl` & `showSuperfishUl` functions? If so, what does the syntax look like to change these methods when calling the plugin:

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('ul.sf-menu').superfish(); // How to override hideSuperfishUl &/or showSuperfishUl?
    }); 

</script>
```

Superfish was written a while back... Is this still the best way to allow users to override plugin <s>functionality</s> functions/methods/other? If not, is there a "best" way?

Comment: Have you reviewed jQuery' [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) documentation?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for reply! I did read the docs, but I did not fully understand how it works in relation to Superfish. Re-reading docs now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to try to answer my own question here... **Please correct me if anything I write below is wrong!** ;)

---

[This article](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-plugin-design-patterns-part-i/) says this:

> ### Extend
>
> In my opinion, this is the least idiomatic way to create a jQuery
>   plugin. It uses the `jQuery.fn.extend` method instead of
>   `jQuery.fn.pluginName`:
>
> ```
> (function($){
>   $.fn.extend({
>       myPlugin: function() {
>           return this.each(function(){
>               // do something
>           });
>       },
>       myOtherPlugin: function() {
>           return this.each(function() {
>               // do something
>           });
>       }
>   });
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> You will find this structure helpful if you need to add a large number
>   of plugin methods to jQuery. I would contend, however, that if your
>   plugin needs to add that many methods, there may be a better way to
>   structure its implementation.
>
> I feel the extend method is used more by programmers transitioning
>   from other JS libraries. I personally find the simple `$.fn.pluginName
>   =` structure to be easier to read, and more in line with what you will normally see in jQuery plugins.

The Superfish JS is using the same code found in the above quote; long story short, `showSuperfishUl()` and `hideSuperfishUl()` are **additional** plugins in the jQuery `$.fn` namespace.

I was able to override said functions like so:

```
jQuery(function(){

    $.fn.showSuperfishUl = function() {
        console.log('OMG');
        return this;
    };

    $.fn.hideSuperfishUl = function() {
        console.log('BECKY');
        return this;
    };

    jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
});
```

Next, [this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern) says:

> ### Provide public access to secondary functions as applicable
>
> ```
> // plugin definition
> $.fn.hilight = function(options) {
>   // iterate and reformat each matched element
>   return this.each(function() {
>       var $this = $(this);
>       // ...
>       var markup = $this.html();
>       // call our format function
>       markup = $.fn.hilight.format(markup);
>       $this.html(markup);
>   });
> };
> // define our format function
> $.fn.hilight.format = function(txt) {
>   return '<strong>' + txt + '</strong>';
> };
> ```
>
> We could have just as easily supported another property on the options
>   object that allowed a callback function to be provided to override the
>   default formatting. That's another excellent way to support
>   customization of your plugin. The technique shown here takes this a
>   step further by actually exposing the format function so that it can
>   be redefined. With this technique it would be possible for others to
>   ship their own custom overrides of your plugin נin other words, it
>   means others can write plugins for your plugin.

### Conclusion:

Both `$.fn.extend` and `$.fn.pluginName.function` are similar and allow the end user to easily override functionality; the former adds new plugins to the jQuery `$.fn` namespace, whereas the latter are functions which are contained within a single `$.fn.pluginName` namespace.

[Summary and Best Practices](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices) says:

> Don't clutter the jQuery.fn object with more than one namespace per
>   plugin.

... therefore, my pick for "best" technique is `$.fn.pluginName.function`.